# Optimize where clause SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out a way to optimize the below SQL query:

```
select * from SOME_TABLE
where (col1 = 123 and col2 = 'abc') 
   or (col1 = 234 and col2 = 'cdf')
   or (col1 = 755 and col2 = 'cvd') ---> I have around 2000 'OR' statements in a single query.
```

Currently this query takes a long time to execute, so is there anyway to make this query run faster?

Comment: Post the explain plan. Without that it's guesswork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a lookup table `CREATE TABLE lookup (col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(3), PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2), KEY(col2)) ORGANIZATION INDEX` or whatever fits your needs
- Make sure you have indexes on your original table (col1 and col2)
- populate the lookup table with your 2000 combinations

Now query

```
SELECT 
  mytable.*
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN lookup ON mytable.col1=lookup.col1 AND mytable.col2=lookup.col2
```

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say without seeing the query plan but I'd imagine this is resolves to a FTS with a lot of CPU doing the OR logic.

If the general pattern is col1=x and col2=y then try creating a table with your 2000 pairs and joining instead.  If your 2000 pairs come from other tables, factor the select statement that retrieves them straight into your SELECT statement here.

Also make sure you've got all your unique and NOT NULL constraints in place as that will make a difference.  Consider an index on col1 & col2, though don't be surprised if it doesn't use it.

Not sure if that's going to do the trick, but post more details if not.

Answer (score 0):

Select only your desired columns, not all (*)... But surely you know that.
But if you have more than 2000 OR in your SQL statement, maybe it's time to change it! If you explain us something more about your database, we'll help you better.